# WMP COM fails to operate under subsequent user impersonations

Tags: c++, com, impersonation, wmp, wmplib

I have a windows service that needs to access the Windows Media Player libraries of all currently logged on users. Since its a service, I must impersonate the logged on user so that calls to the WMP COM will return information in the impersonated user's context (i.e. return the impersonated user's library rather than the system's library). I need to do this for each logged on user.

I am able to successfully impersonate a user in a thread via `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`, get the user's library, then perform a `RevertToSelf`. The problem arises when I try to do this for the next logged on user. It appears that any subsequent calls to the WMP COM always return the first impersonated user's library rather than the current user being impersonated.

Here is a general gist of what I'm doing:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
IWMPCore* Core = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IWMPCore), (void **)&Core);
IWMPMediaCollection* Collection = NULL;
Core->QueryInterface(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), (void **)&Collection);
...
//Do work
...
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: Fairly pointless to post a snippet and then *not* post the lines of code that you are having a problem with.

Comment: @HansPassant Why the down vote? If I knew the exact lines of code I was having the problem on, I wouldn't have needed to post this question. If you needed to see more code in order to answer, why not just ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are releasing all the interfaces?

Have you tried calling [CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and checking in Process Explorer if the WMP dll's are unloaded (Only dlls with a DllCanUnloadNow export will be unloaded though)?

If it still fails then maybe it is impossible for WMP to be unloaded completely and then you might have to use a helper/host process for each user and get the data back into the main process with some form of [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried your suggestion of calling `CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx(0, 0)` to have it free right away. Unfortunately this didn't work. :( Process Explorer shows that the WMP COM object loaded a total of 5 libraries (wmp.dll, wmpps.dll, wmploc.dll, WMVCORE.dll, and WMASF.dll). Only the first of those two libraries export the `DllCanUnloadNow` function. What I don't understand is that `CoUninitialize` is supposed to unload these dlls for me. But even 20-30 minutes or so after calling `CoUninitialize` the dlls were still present.

Comment: Ok got it! I went through it step by step and checked against Process Explorer to see if it was freeing those libraries. As it turns out, I was not releasing one of my objects. I thought I got them all and some how missed one. Thanks for the insight.